# Is this a bug of BoundingRegion of MinBall?

Tags: bugs, regions

## Problem 1

```
ptsTemp = {{-41.78387931007572`, 
44.585268167221834`, -12.53827814970699`}, {-40.47813198820931`, 
44.585268167221834`, -12.53827814970699`}, {-39.172384666342914`, 
44.585268167221834`, -12.53827814970699`}, {-37.866637344476516`, 
44.585268167221834`, -12.53827814970699`}, {-36.56089002261011`, 
44.585268167221834`, -12.53827814970699`}, {-35.25514270074371`, 
44.585268167221834`, -12.53827814970699`}, {-33.94939537887731`, 
44.585268167221834`, -12.53827814970699`}, {-32.64364805701091`, 
44.585268167221834`, -12.53827814970699`}, {-31.33790073514451`, 
44.585268167221834`, -12.53827814970699`}, {-30.032153413278106`, 
44.585268167221834`, -12.53827814970699`}, {-28.726406091411704`, 
44.585268167221834`, -12.53827814970699`}, {-27.420658769545305`, 
44.585268167221834`, -12.53827814970699`}, {-26.114911447678903`, 
44.585268167221834`, -12.53827814970699`}, {-24.8091641258125`, 
44.585268167221834`, -12.53827814970699`}, {-23.503416803946102`, 
44.585268167221834`, -12.53827814970699`}, {-22.1976694820797`, 
44.585268167221834`, -12.53827814970699`}, {-20.891922160213298`, 
44.585268167221834`, -12.53827814970699`}, {-19.586174838346896`, 
44.585268167221834`, -12.53827814970699`}, {-18.280427516480493`, 
44.585268167221834`, -12.53827814970699`}, {-16.974680194614095`, 
44.585268167221834`, -12.53827814970699`}, {-15.668932872747693`, 
44.585268167221834`, -12.53827814970699`}, {-14.36318555088129`, 
44.585268167221834`, -12.53827814970699`}, {-13.05743822901489`, 
44.585268167221834`, -12.53827814970699`}, {-11.75169090714849`, 
44.585268167221834`, -12.53827814970699`}, {-10.445943585282087`, 
44.585268167221834`, -12.53827814970699`}, {-9.140196263415685`, 
44.585268167221834`, -12.53827814970699`}, {-7.834448941549285`, 
44.585268167221834`, -12.53827814970699`}, {-6.5287016196828835`, 
44.585268167221834`, -12.53827814970699`}, {-5.222954297816482`, 
44.585268167221834`, -12.53827814970699`}, {-3.917206975950081`, 
44.585268167221834`, -12.53827814970699`}, {-2.6114596540836796`, 
44.585268167221834`, -12.53827814970699`}, {-1.3057123322172783`, 
44.585268167221834`, -12.53827814970699`}, {0.000034989649122962874`, 
44.585268167221834`, -12.53827814970699`}, {1.3057823115155243`, 
44.585268167221834`, -12.53827814970699`}, {2.6115296333819256`, 
44.585268167221834`, -12.53827814970699`}, {3.917276955248327`, 
44.585268167221834`, -12.53827814970699`}, {5.223024277114728`, 
44.585268167221834`, -12.53827814970699`}, {6.5287715989811295`, 
44.585268167221834`, -12.53827814970699`}, {7.834518920847531`, 
44.585268167221834`, -12.53827814970699`}, {9.140266242713931`, 
44.585268167221834`, -12.53827814970699`}, {10.446013564580333`, 
44.585268167221834`, -12.53827814970699`}, {11.751760886446736`, 
44.585268167221834`, -12.53827814970699`}, {13.057508208313136`, 
44.585268167221834`, -12.53827814970699`}, {14.363255530179536`, 
44.585268167221834`, -12.53827814970699`}, {15.669002852045939`, 
44.585268167221834`, -12.53827814970699`}, {16.97475017391234`, 
44.585268167221834`, -12.53827814970699`}, {18.28049749577874`, 
44.585268167221834`, -12.53827814970699`}, {19.58624481764514`, 
44.585268167221834`, -12.53827814970699`}, {20.891992139511544`, 
44.585268167221834`, -12.53827814970699`}, {22.197739461377946`, 
44.585268167221834`, -12.53827814970699`}, {23.503486783244348`, 
44.585268167221834`, -12.53827814970699`}, {24.809234105110747`, 
44.585268167221834`, -12.53827814970699`}, {26.11498142697715`, 
44.585268167221834`, -12.53827814970699`}, {27.42072874884355`, 
44.585268167221834`, -12.53827814970699`}, {28.72647607070995`, 
44.585268167221834`, -12.53827814970699`}, {30.032223392576352`, 
44.585268167221834`, -12.53827814970699`}, {31.337970714442754`, 
44.585268167221834`, -12.53827814970699`}, {32.64371803630915`, 
44.585268167221834`, -12.53827814970699`}, {33.94946535817556`, 
44.585268167221834`, -12.53827814970699`}, {35.25521268004196`, 
44.585268167221834`, -12.53827814970699`}};
```

If we run this code for many times, some bounding ball centers are not at the center points.
I'm on Mac of Mathematica 12.1

```
Show@Table[Graphics3D[BoundingRegion[ptsTemp, "MinBall"]], {i, 100}]
```

## Problem2

```
data={{49.997,-7.49994,5.00001},{49.997,7.49939,5.00001}, 
{50.,7.49939,20.0001},{50.,-7.49994,20.0001}, 
{49.997,12.4994,-4.9091*10^-6},{49.997,7.49939,5.00001}, 
{49.997,-7.49994,5.00001},{49.997,-12.5,-4.9091*10^-6}, 
{49.997,12.4994,24.9993},{50.,7.49939,20.0001}, 
{49.997,7.49939,5.00001},{49.997,12.4994,-4.9091*10^-6}, 
{49.997,-12.5,25.0001},{50.,-7.49994,20.0001},{50.,7.49939,20.0001}, 
{49.997,12.4994,24.9993},{49.997,-12.5,-4.9091*10^-6}, 
{49.997,-7.49994,5.00001},{50.,-7.49994,20.0001}, 
{49.997,-12.5,25.0001},{-50.0001,-7.49994,20.0001}, 
{-50.0001,7.50015,20.0001},{-50.0001,7.50015,5.00001}, 
{-50.0001,-7.49994,5.00001},{-50.0001,12.4994,24.9993}, 
{-50.0001,7.50015,20.0001},{-50.0001,-7.49994,20.0001}, 
{-50.0001,-12.5,24.9993},{-50.0001,12.5002,-4.9091*10^-6}, 
{-50.0001,7.50015,5.00001}}


BoundingRegion[data,"MinBall"]
```

Tested on windows with Mathematica 13.3, the evaluation seems to be stuck and can't to be `Abort` by Menu or Shortcut.

As a comparison, `BoundingRegion[data,"FastBall"]` is normal.

Looks like those `-4.9091*10^-6` is a reason causes this problem that you can change them into `0`.

But `data[[1;;20]]` is OK.

---

## Update

problem 1 seems to be solved in 13.3, problem 2 is a new finding.

[image]

Comment: `ParallelTable` helps.

Comment: It must be a bug. I repeatedly executed it and eventually got a ball `Ball[{-12., 44., -11.}, 32.]` and some points were outside. It will occasionally happen even if I use exact numbers like `Round[ptsTemp, .1] // Rationalize;`. Changing the `WorkingPrecision` had no effect either - I still got points outside sometimes. This does not seem to happen if you use `"FastBall"` instead. 2D doesn't seem to be affected: `pts2d = Most /@ ptsTemp;
Graphics[{Point[pts2d], Opacity[.5], 
  BoundingRegion[pts2d, "MinDisk"]}]`

Comment: This appears to be fixed in 12.2.0.0 and I'm not getting different a different MinBall after lots of evaluations. I will add the bugs tag.

Comment: @flinty Thanks, glad to hear about that.

Comment: @flinty a new problem.